# Environment variable in the Docker file for a specific RUN command

Tags: docker

In my Dockerfile, I have:

```
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
CMD NODE_ENV=$ENVIRONMENT npm run serve
```

However, I need to run another command BEFORE serve, and make sure NODE_ENV Is set for that one too.
I tried this:

```
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
RUN NODE_ENV=$ENVIRONMENT npm run upgrade
CMD NODE_ENV=$ENVIRONMENT npm run serve
```

However, NODE_ENV doesn't seem to be set for RUN.

What am I missing?

(Note: edited tag removed)

Comment: Did you pass the environment value when building the image? e.g. `docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT`. Can you log into the container and execute `env` to check if the environment value is set?

Comment: How can you tell it's not getting set?  (With that syntax you should be able to see it in the `docker build` output.)  Why not just set `ENV NODE_ENV=$ENVIRONMENT` to set it more permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables set in a RUN statement do not persist.

It's like you open a shell, set the environment variable and close the shell session again. The next shell will not have the environment variable you set in the previous shell session.

How to fix this? Add the NODE_ENV Variable as an ENV in your dockerfile

```
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT \
    NODE_ENV=$ENVIRONMENT
RUN npm run upgrade
CMD npm run serve
```